# Choosing 2 or 3 values out 3 values after calculating their closeness

Tags: algorithms, functional-programming, computer-science

I want to find a specific algorithm to choose either 2 or 3 out of 3 given values.
Like if I have a set of values 10,11,12 all three are close enough so I will calculate the mean of the value and return the mean.
For another example if the values are 6,10,12. then I will choose 10 and 12 and calculate the mean and return the mean.
Though these value can not necessarily be of of this range ,  they can go in thousands as well .
But there will only be three number of values . I hope I am clear enough.
I am not sure how to proceed over this and I need some help .
Thank you

Comment: Tip: if you were writing a recipe (like in cooking) for this, what would it look like?

Comment: see **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)**. "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: ...also, please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657962/algorithm-to-choosing-2-or-3-values-out-of-3-values-after-calculating-how-close "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 0):

Use [statistical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics) analysis.

You're looking to reject a value that is outside some "normal" range for the 3.  There are several ways to interpret what the normal range is and what [outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) are, so you'll have to pick one that meets your needs, in particular with such a small sample size.

From the wikipedia article on outliers and [their detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Definitions_and_detection):

> > There is no rigid mathematical definition of what constitutes an outlier; determining whether or not an observation is an outlier is ultimately a subjective exercise.  There are various methods of outlier detection...